# How to change a value so that it doesn't have static lifetime in Rust

Tags: rust, pyo3

I have the following function that uses PyO3 to call a python function and get a result (in this case, an `int` that gets assigned to a `i32`):

```
fn run_python<'a, T: FromPyObject<'a> + Clone>(func_name: &str) -> Result<T, ()> {
    Python::with_gil(|py| {
        let pyapi = match py.import("pyapi") {
            Ok(v) => v,
            Err(e) => { e.print_and_set_sys_last_vars(py); return Err(()) },
        };

        let locals = [("pyapi", pyapi)].into_py_dict(py);
        let eval_result: PyResult<&PyAny> = py.eval("pyapi.{}(**kwargs)", None, Some(&locals));

        let wrapped_obj: &PyAny = match eval_result {
            Ok(v) => v,
            Err(e) => { e.print_and_set_sys_last_vars(py); return Err(()) },
        };

        let unwrapped_result: PyResult<T> = wrapped_obj.extract();

        match unwrapped_result {
            Ok(v) => return Ok(v.clone()),
            Err(e) => return Err(()),
        };
    })
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'p` due to conflicting requirements
   --> src\bin\launch.rs:89:30
    |
89  |         let eval_result = py.eval("pyapi.{}(**kwargs)", None, Some(&locals));
    |                              ^^^^
    |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 82:22...
   --> src\bin\launch.rs:82:22
    |
82  |       Python::with_gil(|py| {
    |  ______________________^
83  | |         let pyapi = match py.import("pyapi") {
84  | |             Ok(v) => v,
85  | |             Err(e) => { e.print_and_set_sys_last_vars(py); return Err(()) },
...   |
101 | |         };
102 | |     })
    | |_____^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
   --> src\bin\launch.rs:89:30
    |
89  |         let eval_result = py.eval("pyapi.{}(**kwargs)", None, Some(&locals));
    |                              ^^^^
    = note: expected `pyo3::Python<'_>`
               found `pyo3::Python<'_>`
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the function body at 81:15...
   --> src\bin\launch.rs:81:15
    |
81  | fn run_python<'a, T: FromPyObject<'a> + Clone>(func_name: &str) -> Result<T, ()> {
    |               ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
   --> src\bin\launch.rs:96:57
    |
96  |         let unwrapped_result: PyResult<T> = wrapped_obj.extract();
    |                                                         ^^^^^^^
    = note: expected `pyo3::FromPyObject<'_>`
               found `pyo3::FromPyObject<'a>`
```

I'm very new to Rust, and am probably doing something silly (and very likely could be an X/Y problem). How can I get a value out of `py.eval` that doesn't have a lifetime tied to the python interpreter (which is what I'm assuming is going on here)?

Comment: If you're new to Rust, I might propose that interfacing with Python is not a great project for learning. The borrow checker is a beast, and trying to learn it while understanding the complexities of any (let alone Rust's) FFI is going to be incredibly complicated.

Comment: Normally I’d try this first and answer, but it’s some time to set up. Does `run_python<T: for<'a> FromPyObject<'a> + Clone>` work? Possibly `run_python<T: for<'a> FromPyObject<'a> + Clone + 'static>`? (And maybe you wanted `+ 'static` instead of `+ Clone` to begin with?)

Comment: @Ry- Yep, the first suggestion did the trick.  Would you like to make an answer so that I can accept it? Bonus points if there's a link to docs that explain what's going on in more detail than https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html .  Thanks!

Comment: If Ry wants to post an answer, I can remove mine. I had written an answer with another type of fix, until I realized the `for<'b>` approach is likely the best option, so I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix that Ry suggests, seems to work well. Using `for<'p>` lets the compiler defer evaluation of the lifetime until it's needed when processing the code that calls `.extract()`. And the lifetime, `'p`, doesn't need to be specified in the function's generic parameter list. Also, the `Clone` bound wasn't required.

```rust
fn run_python<T>(func_name: &str) -> Result<T, ()>
where
    T: for<'p> FromPyObject<'p>,
{
    let guard = Python::acquire_gil();
    let py    = guard.python();    
    match || -> _ { // try...
        let pyapi  = py.import("pyapi")?; // throw...
        let locals = [("pyapi", pyapi)].into_py_dict(py);            
        py.eval(&format!("pyapi.{}(**kwargs)", func_name), 
                None, 
                Some(&locals))?.extract()
    }() { // catch...
        Err(e) => {
            // Error handling specific to Pyo3.
            e.print_and_set_sys_last_vars(py);
            // Return the error type spec'd in the fn signature.
            Err(())
        },
        Ok(obj) => Ok(obj),
    }    
}
```

The only limitation to this approach would be the type that `.extract()` converts to needs to not depend on the lifetime of the type it's converting from. For instance if `run_python()` could return list of strings, this is possible:

```rust
let values: Vec<String> = run_python("make_string_list").unwrap(); // OK.
```

But this would produce a lifetime related compiler error although `.extract()` is capable of producing this type under the right condtions:

```rust
let values: Vec<&str> = run_python("make_string_list").unwrap(); // Error.
```

If `run_python()` needed to be able to produce lifetime dependent values, then a solution could be for the caller to grab the GIL, and pass in a `Python` instance. The function could look like this:

```rust
fn run_python<'p, T>(func_name: &str, py: Python<'p>) -> PyResult<T>
where
    T: FromPyObject<'p>,
{
    let pyapi  = py.import("pyapi")?;
    let locals = [("pyapi", pyapi)].into_py_dict(py);            
    py.eval(&format!("pyapi.{}(**kwargs)", func_name), 
            None, 
            Some(&locals))?.extract()
}
```

---

*I started writing another answer before I realized the suggestion to use `for<>` was the best alternative. I had assumed that the return value had some dependency on the GIL, but `.extract()` returns types that don't depend on the GIL.*

*In the previous answer, I suggested ways to deal with Python objects that need to be held beyond GIL lifetimes.  This involved converting GIL-Dependent types to GIL-Independent types using `.to_object(py)`, and back again using methods like `.cast_as::<PyType>(py)` when they're needed.*

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer (I don't get the impression that Ry is too worried about the points). I'm trying to understand why the `match` you have is idiomatic; what's the reason to have the `let pyapi` and `let locals` inside the match vs. outside?  My guess is that it's due to the `?` on `py.import` needing to flow into the match, and that's supposed to be cleaner than returning early?

Comment: The match statement is probably more "elegant" (if it could be called that) than idiomatic. What's going on there is  the `match` argument is actually a closure, and the parenthesis immediately after the last right-curly-brace invoke it.  So the let bindings are local to the closure.  The idea here was to capture any errors in the closure block with the `?` convention, and handle in the match body below the closure. I haven't seen any other cases of this monstrosity (?) - I stumbled on it when I was agonizing over the lack of try/catch semantics like other OO languages. @EliStevens